# irregular div with empty left-bottom corner

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div where I will put text. Div should look like this:

```
qqqqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqqqq
  qqqqqqqqqqq
    qqqqqqqqq
      qqqqqqq
        qqqqq
```

I dont want to see text in the lower left corner, but with `text-align: left;` it should look like on my example.

Comment: Not sure if you have control over when to break a line, or if this is just automatic overflow.

Comment: If the amount of text is variable, I don't think it's possible without JavaScript.

Comment: IE 10 only http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-exclusions/#shapes

Comment: I think it won't work with shapes. I tried to use Triangle Bottom Left with float left, so text would be like on my example, but it didnt work, browser left space for square. How can i do it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

try like this

The HTML

```
<div>
    <div>qqqqqqqqqqqqq</div>
    <div>qqqqqqqqqqqqq</div>
    <div>qqqqqqqqqqqqq</div>        
    <div>qqqqqqqqqqqqq</div>    
    <div>qqqqqqqqqqqqq</div>
    <div>qqqqqqqqqqqqq</div>
    <div>qqqqqqqqqqq</div>
    <div>qqqqqqqqq</div>    
    <div>qqqqqqq</div>
    <div>qqqqq</div>        
</div>
```

The CSS

```
div
{
text-align:right
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Divs are rectangular. You either need to use `text-align: right;`, put nbsp's to shove the content over, or use other divs to fill the area.

Your example seems like a perfect fit for `text-align: right;` since the text is flush right.

Comment: I think his text must overflow into new lines and he has no indication of when to start a new line.  Not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

**HTML**

```
<div class="div1">
qqqqqqqqqqqqq<br>
qqqqqqqqqqqqq<br>
qqqqqqqqqqqqq<br>
qqqqqqqqqqqqq<br>
qqqqqqqqqqqqq<br>
qqqqqqqqqqqqq<br>
qqqqqqqqqqq<br>
qqqqqqqqq<br>
qqqqqqq<br>
qqqqq<br>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1{
width:150px;
height:200px;
background:#eaeaea;
text-align:right
}
```

[Check the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/zXCZM/)